# Thinking Sphinx - How to tell it to use ActiveRecord "include" feature, to avoid subsidiary SQL lookups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Sphinx & ThinkingSphinx are working great for me, however when a search returns back an array of results (models), I then notice in my logs that there are a large number of subsidiary SQL lookups to retrieve any associated models, these associations are defined within my model classes.

If I was just using ActiveRecord I could use the "include" feature to retrieve these associated records as part of the original search query, for example:

> Booking.find_all_by_date(Date.today, **:include => [:event,
>   :organizer, :sessions]**)

But I'm not sure how to implement this performance optimization in ThinkingSphinx, has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it exactly the same way - use `:include`, it'll get passed through to the underlying ActiveRecord query when Thinking Sphinx translates Sphinx results to ActiveRecord objects.

**Edit**: Since [TS v3](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v3/searching.html#advanced), the `:include` option is now contained within the `:sql` option:

```
Booking.search(:sql => {:include => [:event, :organiser, :sessions]})
```

Comment: Thanks again Pat - can't believe I missed that!